# Android how to resize a text inside an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText`. I would like to resize the text inside the `EditText`, if the length of the text is bigger than 10 for example.

How to do this?

Thank you. Appreciate!

Comment: what exactly you need to do ? need to reduce the fontsize/textsize when the number of characters exceeds 10 ?

Comment: it is already written @sunil  "I would like to resize the text inside the EditText, if the length of the text is bigger than 10 for example." . What are you asking?

Comment: @CodersParadise i need to clarify whether he thought of doing `text-justification` or `resizing` itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may prefer using a TextWatcher instead of an OnKeyListener (which obviously targets hardware keys) :

```
    final float size1 = 30, size2 = 15;

    final EditText edit = new EditText(this);
    edit.setTextSize(size1);

    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length() > 10) {
                edit.setTextSize(size2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick :

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(et.getText().length()>10) {
            et.setTextSize(newValue);
        } else {
            et.setTextSize(oldValue);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
if(myEditText.getText().toString().lenght() > 10)
{
        myEditText.setTextSize(6);
} 
else 
{
        myEditText.setTextSize(10);
}
```